# Swift override init() in class subclassed from Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, swift

I have an Objective-C class and here is its `init()`:

```
- (id)init
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:@"xxxViewController" bundle:nil];
    if (self)
    {

    }
    return self;
}
```

I have a Swift class that is a subclass of this.
How do I override the `init` of the superclass in the Swift class? I would like to move the `initWithNibName` into the Swift class.

Here is the `init` in the Swift class that I have tried:

```
init() {
    super.init()
}
```

I get the error:

> Must call a designated intializer of the super class

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24522186/8125224

Answer (score 0):

Since `init()` is not a designated initializer (in this case, `initWithNibName:bundle:` is), we need to let the compiler know that it is in fact a designated initializer. We can do that by appending an attribute to the declaration in the header (after the last attribute, but before the semicolon):

```
@interface MyClass : Superclass
- (instancetype)init NS_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER;
@end
```